# Java: Reflection overuse?

Tags: java, reflection

I am wondering whether I am overusing java reflection.
I have a class which is a data holder for a couple of maps. I have public get(...) methods which given  a key as input return the value associated with it in the corresponding map.
Since the maps are large I load them only when I actually want to access them. So, in every get(...) methods, I check whether the map is null. If it is, I call the corresponding loadMap(..) method.
Here is a sample code snippet

```
 public getId(String name)  
 {
     try
     {
     if(nameMap1 == null)
        loadNameMap1();
     } catch(...) {....}

     return nameMap1.getId(name);
 }
```

The problem is that I have multiple maps. So, for loading each map I have a different loadMap(..) method and the try catch block in the get(...) methods. So, instead of that I wrote a method called loadMap(Object map, String methodName) which uses reflection to call the appropriate method, and handles all exceptions.

```
private synchronized void loadMap(Object map, String methodName)
{
if (map == null)
    try
    {
    Method method = this.getClass().getDeclaredMethod(methodName, new Class[0]);
    method.invoke(this, new Object[0]);
    } 
    catch (..)
}
```

Am I overusing reflection here? Is there a better way to do this? Does this qualify as "limited use of reflection" as written in [Effective Java by Joshua Bloch](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/effective/)
(Side note: I cannot refactor the class into multiple classes )

Comment: "I cannot refactor the class into multiple classes". And why is that? You can keep the current interface to the outside, but the implementation can be refactored (into using some MapLoader interface), no?

Comment: @Thilo: I do not have control over the design.

Comment: If you have no control over the design, how come you can decide to use reflection? Surely adding some private inner classes (i.e. implementation details) do not conflict with the design of things.

Comment: @Thilo: Using reflection is allowed. Private inner classes could be used. But I don't see how that can be done here.

Comment: My answer uses anonymous inner classes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
// could also be static
private Map<String, Callable<Map>> myLoaders;

private synchronized void loadMap(Object map, String mapName)
{
if (map == null)
    try
    {
       Callable<Map> mapLoader = myLoaders.get(mapName);
       map = mapLoader.call();
    } 
    catch (..)
}

// and in the constructor or other init code
myLoaders.put("map1", new Callable<Map>(){
     Map call(){
        // load map 1
     }});
```

I think, though that if all you are doing is move a common try/catch logic from a couple of methods were it needs to be repeated to a single place, this is the wrong approach. You lose a lot of compiler error checking support this way. Some people would use a tool like Aspect/J for this, but I think you just have to live with the fact that Java has no real facility for this, reduce the clutter to a minimum by using shared private functions, and accept the couple of copy/pasted lines. As long as there is no "real code" in those lines, it is not really harmful code duplication.

So:

```
 public getId(String name){
     try{
        if (nameMap1 == null)
            loadNameMap1();
        }
      catch (....){
          privateHelperFunctionThatCutsThisDownToOneLine(name, "id", "nameMap1");
      }
  }

  // you are left with the above repetitive three (or seven) lines,
  // but that is Java for you...
  // in return, you get nice, static compile-time error checking


 private void privateHelperFunctionThatCutsThisDownToOneLine(){
      // all the long repeated code in the exception handler
      // goes here.
 }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have implemented your solution. Just out of curiosity, is this some kind of pattern?

Comment: In Perl, they call it "dispatch table". In Java, it is probably just bad design (unless you want it configurable/extensible at runtime, then it makes sense).

Comment: Why is it bad design? How can it be improved? ( I probably won't be able to change the design but it will still be great to know )

Comment: I'll add an alternative approach.

Answer (score 2):

I'd say yes you are overusing reflection.

Perhaps you should take a more OO approach

```
public interface MapMaker <K,V> {
public Map<K,V> create();
}

public class LazyMap<K,V> implements Map<K,V> {

private MapMaker<K,V> creation;
private Map<K,V> theMap = null;

public LazyMap( MapMaker<K,V> creation) {
  this.creation=creation;
}

protected Map<K,V> getMap() {
  if( theMap == null) {
    synchronized(this) {
      if( theMap == null ) {
         theMap = creation.create();
      }
    }
  }
  return theMap;
}
//Map interface
public V get(Object key) { return getMap().get(key); }
//repeat for all
}
```

Comment: Good answer but you are implementing a pattern known as *double check locking* in `getMap()` and this pattern is known to fail as described in [developerworks](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-dcl.html)

Comment: I know. There isn't AFAIK, a decent way to do this, even with volatile, in java.

Comment: I just did some browsing on the subject and since Java 5 has a new [memory model](http://xlct.it/faz2fl) the double checked lock should be working on a Java 5 or higher JVM. See also at the end of this [article](http://xlct.it/ekzRnO)

Answer (score 2):

You don't want to load all the maps because they are too large. But using your method you're gonna end up with everything loaded in memory eventually. You may have a look at [ehcache](http://ehcache.org/) which may be configured a a lazy map system with element eviction when no longer needed.

Comment: +1 for mentioning that an eviction strategy may also be necessary.